# How to add a repository in Git Hub?

Tags: html, git, github, zip

Please give the steps to follow

I tried to upload my zip files of HTML project and my repository is still empty. My repository is still empty after trying to upload.

Comment: Please further elaborate the steps you tried

Answer (score 0):

Go to profile at the top right of the page in github and then go to the `your repositories` option. Then select new, and enter the name and then if want to write the code or you can add the files and click create.